# In online matches, what rules are used if all players have "Preferred Rules" off?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When playing online in Super Smash Bros. Ultimate, there's a Preferred Rules option to prefer matches that match a specific ruleset. (Time/Stock/Stamina, Match Length, Items On/Off). What happens when all players in a match have preferred rules turned off? Is there a default ruleset the game falls back on?

Comment: I would presume that it randomly picks one player's ruleset to use, the same way it does so if everyone has Preferred Rules on but no one's rules quite match. (Even if the option is off, the ruleset would still exist, the game just isn't considering it during matchmaking.) Not confident enough to make this an answer though.

Comment: The online ruleset options cannot be adjusted when preferred rules are turned off.

Comment: They still *exist* though. The options maintain their state as they were last set (which would be the default if they have never been), whether they're being used for matchmaking or not. My theory is that if no one has "preferred" active, the game picks someone's at random anyway.